# find /myMusic -type f | grep --regexp , regular expression to pipe only mp3 files?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, ubuntu, grep

I'm struggling to write a regular expression to find all my mp3 files.  I want to pipe out all files with the last four characters being either .mp3 .Mp3 .mP3 or .MP3

What's the correct pattern that should follow --regexp?

```
find /myMusic -type f | grep --regexp
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
find /myMusic -type f -iname '*.mp3'
```

The `-iname` matches the name (`*.mp3` here) ignoring case.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the pipe or the `grep`, `find` can use the regex with the `-regex` option. Try this:

```
find /myMusic -type f -regex '.*\.[Mm][Pp]3'
```

Comment: You can use `-iname` which does search case-insensitively. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
find /myMusic -type f | grep -i "mp3$"
```

-i makes the match case insensitive, and "$" specifies the end of the line.

Answer (score 1):

This pattern works:

```
^.*\.[mM][pP]3$
```

Here it is in action:

http://regexr.com?2vn7d